# iOS8 APNs,cancel a notification from notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I need to cancel a notification from the notification center on iOS8.

You need at least 10 reputation publish pictures, but you can look at the two pictures in the following URL to see what I mean: http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid-307533.html. Image one has two notifications, but in image two 未接来电(4) has been 未接来电(5).

I know the cancelAllLocalNotifications API, but how can I cancel a single notification in iOS8 new api?

Comment: Could you give more information about your question? For instance, are you writing an app in Objective-C?

Comment: YES.An voip app.when have a miss call from someone,i need to clear other miss calls of him.and push a new notification,miss call(2).Can you understand?my english so poor.

Comment: http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid-307533.html . in two image 未接来电(4) has been 未接来电(5).but 未接来电(2) always be there.